# Trying to render a page with two textbox and login button i react js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

i am trying to render a page with two textbox and login button in react js with Asp.net MVc as follows but only image is rendering nothing else rendering.
in 
index.cshtml
 inside head section css rendered
 and in body section react cdn and reactjs file has been added

```
@{
        Layout = null;
}
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper" id="signup"></div>
    <link href="Assets/Css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Assets/JS/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Assets/JS/react.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Assets/JS/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Assets/JS/remarkable.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/jsx" src="@Url.Content("~/Assets/JS/login.jsx")"></script> 
</body>
 <!--   Core JS Files   -->
<script src="~/Assets/JS/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

login.jsx

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
 render() {
    return (
         <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
   </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<NameForm />,document.getElementById('signup'));
```

All design part mentioned but while declaring class the error
"JSX:Parser Unable to communicate with jsx parser". Error is occuring..So Any idea how to create login form in react js using asp.net mvc. would be appreciated

Comment: You should post what't the code you have tired so far...

Comment: @AhmadF i have post the code what i am trying